# Create numpy masks from images using matplolib

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to create a set of images and their corresponding masks using matplotlib. The goal is to use these to train an object detection deep learning algorithm.

Create image:

```
on_off=[]
gridspec=random.sample([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,7],3)

fig, axes=plt.subplots(2,3,figsize=(7,7),gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': gridspec})

if random.random()<0.3:
    fig.set_facecolor(random.sample(colors,1)[0])

subplot_dict={}

for i,ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    subplot_dict[i]={}
    
    if random.random()<0.2:
        on_off.append(0)
        ax.axis('off')
        continue
        
    red, black=draw_subplot(ax, number=random.sample(range(1,10),1)[0], number_buffer=random.sample(range(0,3),1)[0])
    on_off.append(1)
    subplot_dict[i]['red']=red
    subplot_dict[i]['black']=black

plt.show()
```

Create mask

```
fig,axes=plt.subplots(2,3,figsize=(7,7),gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': (gridspec)})
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    if on_off[i]:
        ax.set_facecolor(colors[i])
        for spine in ax.spines.values():
            spine.set_edgecolor(colors[i])
        
        ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='both',bottom=False, left=False,labelbottom=False, labelleft=False)
    else:
        ax.remove()
        ax.axis('off')
```

This results in the example image and mask shown below.

The mask itself is ok, however, I need it to be in a specific numpy array format:

1. Number of channels = 1
2. The region corresponding to each subplot (marked by a different color in the mask) in the numpt array should all have the same value - 1,2,3,4 etc.

That is the mask should look like:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 2 2 2 2
1 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 
0 3 3 3 2 2 2 2
0 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 
0 3 3 3 0 0 4 4 
0 0 0 0 0 0 4 4
```

How do I create this numpy array from either the mask or from the matplotlib code?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem. How can a randomly gengerated color patches help with object detection model?

Comment: I'm trying to see how to convert the mask of different colors to a numpy array of the given format. So I know that a certain patch within the image is of a certain color, I would like that section in the array to have a certain value.